# DataGridView not updating values on button click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, wpfdatagrid

In my Application has two windows . Main Window contains one `DataGridview` , and one Button (Add). when click button it opens another window and it contains 2 text boxes, and button.

On the window 2 , when click button, text box values need to send and display to the Main window `DataGrid`!

This is the 2 files!..

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win = new Window1(this);
            win.Show();
        }

    }
```

window1.cs

```
      public Window1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();     
            }
            private MainWindow m = null;
            public Window1(Window callingFrom)
            {
                m = callingFrom as MainWindow;
                InitializeComponent();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("ID");
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                m.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                m.dataGrid1.UpdateLayout();
            }
      private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                DataView dv = m.dataGrid1.ItemsSource as DataView;

                DataTable dt = dv.Table;
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Name"] = txt1.Text;
                dr["ID"] = txt2.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
               // this.Close();
                m.dataGrid1.UpdateLayout();
            }

}
```

The problem is when close the window1 and again open the window1 to add values to `Datagridview`, Main window's `datagrid` view got replaced instead of adding values!

(It is updating values one by one up to close the window 1 )

How can resolve this!

Thank you!

Comment: I see you're asking the same question repeatedly and ignoring the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a new `DataTable` with nothing in it. It's empty. Then you added one item to it, and you *replaced* the old `ItemsSource` with a view on that new `DataTable`, which has exactly one new item in it.

Of course the old items are no longer seen in the grid. You went to a lot of trouble to get rid of them.

Think of it this way: You have a shoebox with a pair of shoes in it. You throw it away in the trash, the trash men take it to the dump, it's gone, you will never see it again. Understand: If the shoes were in the box when you threw the box away, you don't have those shoes any more. They went with the box, because they were *inside* the box, and the box is gone, so the shoes are gone also.

Then, the next day, you get a new box and put a new pair of shoes in it.

How many pairs of shoes are in the new box? Exactly one pair of shoes, and that pair is the *new* pair that you just put in the box, not the old pair that was in the other box. You threw the old pair in the trash when you threw away the box they were in.

It's a little bit like if you get in your car and drive to the store, when the car arrives at the store, *you arrive with it*. Because you're *contained within the car*. This is merely an analogy: I don't mean to suggest that you personally are actually a discarded pair of shoes, or a row in a `GridView`.

Here's how to do this in a less wrong way:

```
public class GridItem 
{
    public GridItem(String i, String n)
    {
        ID = i;
        Name = n;
    }

    public String ID { get; protected set; }
    public String Name { get; protected set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<GridItem> GridItems { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridItems = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>();

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = GridItems;
    }

    private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 win = new Window1(this);
        win.Show();
    }
}

public class Window1
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();     
    }

    private MainWindow m = null;

    public Window1(Window callingFrom)
    {
        m = callingFrom as MainWindow;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //  Because m.GridItems is an ObservableCollection, which has been assigned 
        //  to the datagrid's ItemsSource property, the datagrid will magically 
        //  update itself with the new item. When you add new items, the old items will 
        //  still be seen because you are adding them to the same old collection 
        //  instead of creating a new empty collection every time. 
        m.GridItems.Add(new GridItem(txt2.Text, txt1.Text));
    }
}
```

Somewhat off topic, but you should name things in a way that makes sense. `txt2` means nothing. You should call it `txtID` or something that says what it is, so anybody looking at the code can instantly understand what it is. `m` is also not a very informative name.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It working as I expected.! And thank you for your comments! I will follow those  things in future !